# Splitting dynamic values in two columns into multiple columns - Removing Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling to create a query which can split multiple values in a column into multiple columns to help "de-duplicate" a data set.

Best explained in data below, but basically you'll notice an interval field which is a DENSE RANK across the ID, START, FINISH, DURATION, COD columns. Due to multiple overlapping PSSID and CSSID values these intervals are duplicated. I'd like to know if there's a good way to dynamically split the overlapping PSSID and CSSID fields into multiple columns...! Ok, so what do I actually mean...

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
ID  START   FINISH  DURA    COD INT PSSID   CSSID
A1  33.18   33.27   0.09    ST  15  N13045  NULL
A1  33.18   33.27   0.09    ST  15  N13046  NULL
A1  33.27   33.285  0.015   DU  16  N13046  NULL
A1  33.27   33.285  0.015   DU  16  NULL    N20015
A1  33.27   33.285  0.015   DU  16  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.27   33.285  0.015   DU  16  NULL    N20033
A1  33.285  33.35   0.065   BM  17  N13046  NULL
A1  33.285  33.35   0.065   BM  17  NULL    N20015
A1  33.285  33.35   0.065   BM  17  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.285  33.35   0.065   BM  17  NULL    N20033
A1  33.35   33.395  0.045   DM  18  N13046  NULL
A1  33.35   33.395  0.045   DM  18  NULL    N20015
A1  33.35   33.395  0.045   DM  18  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.35   33.395  0.045   DM  18  NULL    N20033
A1  33.395  33.44   0.045   DN  19  N13046  NULL
A1  33.395  33.44   0.045   DN  19  NULL    N20015
A1  33.395  33.44   0.045   DN  19  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.395  33.44   0.045   DN  19  NULL    N20033
A1  33.44   33.485  0.045   BM  20  N13046  NULL
A1  33.44   33.485  0.045   BM  20  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.44   33.485  0.045   BM  20  NULL    N20033
A1  33.44   33.485  0.045   BM  20  NULL    N20034
A1  33.485  33.51   0.025   DN  21  N13046  NULL
A1  33.485  33.51   0.025   DN  21  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.485  33.51   0.025   DN  21  NULL    N20033
A1  33.485  33.51   0.025   DN  21  NULL    N20034
A1  33.51   33.595  0.085   DB  22  N13046  NULL
A1  33.51   33.595  0.085   DB  22  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.51   33.595  0.085   DB  22  NULL    N20034
A1  33.595  33.665  0.07    DN  23  N13046  NULL
A1  33.595  33.665  0.07    DN  23  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.595  33.665  0.07    DN  23  NULL    N20034
A1  33.665  33.785  0.12    DB  24  NULL    N2001516
A1  33.785  33.79   0.005   YS  25  NULL    NULL
A1  33.79   33.83   0.04    BM  26  NULL    NULL
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
ID  START   FINISH  DURA    COD INT PSSID1  PSSID2  CSSID1  CSSID2      CSSID3
A1  33.18   33.27   0.09    ST  15  N13046  N13045  NULL    NULL        NULL
A1  33.27   33.285  0.015   DU  16  N13046  NULL    N20015  N2001516    N20033
A1  33.285  33.35   0.065   BM  17  N13046  NULL    N20015  N2001516    N20033
A1  33.35   33.395  0.045   DM  18  N13046  NULL    N20015  N2001516    N20033
A1  33.395  33.44   0.045   DN  19  N13046  NULL    N20015  N2001516    N20033
A1  33.44   33.485  0.045   BM  20  N13046  NULL    N20034  N2001516    N20033
A1  33.485  33.51   0.025   DN  21  N13046  NULL    N20034  N2001516    N20033
A1  33.51   33.595  0.085   DB  22  N13046  NULL    N20034  N2001516    NULL
A1  33.595  33.665  0.07    DN  23  N13046  NULL    N20034  N2001516    NULL
A1  33.665  33.785  0.12    DB  24  NULL    NULL    NULL    N2001516    NULL
A1  33.785  33.79   0.005   YS  25  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
A1  33.79   33.83   0.04    BM  26  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
```

To make matters worse this is just a small fraction of sample data, there may be more than three PSSID, CSSID fields for a given interval (though this should have an upper limit of 5). The query therefore needs to be dynamic to allow for this.

I'm using SQL Server 2012. The schema for the above data is supplied below:

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData
    ([ID] varchar(2), [START] decimal(9,2), [FINISH] decimal(9,2), [DURA] decimal(9,2), [COD] varchar(2), [INT] int, [PSSID] varchar(6), [CSSID] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO #SampleData
    ([ID], [START], [FINISH], [DURA], [COD], [INT], [PSSID], [CSSID])
VALUES
    ('A1', 33.18, 33.27, 0.09, 'ST', 15, 'N13045', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.18, 33.27, 0.09, 'ST', 15, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.27, 33.285, 0.015, 'DU', 16, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.27, 33.285, 0.015, 'DU', 16, NULL, 'N20015'),
    ('A1', 33.27, 33.285, 0.015, 'DU', 16, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.27, 33.285, 0.015, 'DU', 16, NULL, 'N20033'),
    ('A1', 33.285, 33.35, 0.065, 'BM', 17, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.285, 33.35, 0.065, 'BM', 17, NULL, 'N20015'),
    ('A1', 33.285, 33.35, 0.065, 'BM', 17, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.285, 33.35, 0.065, 'BM', 17, NULL, 'N20033'),
    ('A1', 33.35, 33.395, 0.045, 'DM', 18, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.35, 33.395, 0.045, 'DM', 18, NULL, 'N20015'),
    ('A1', 33.35, 33.395, 0.045, 'DM', 18, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.35, 33.395, 0.045, 'DM', 18, NULL, 'N20033'),
    ('A1', 33.395, 33.44, 0.045, 'DN', 19, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.395, 33.44, 0.045, 'DN', 19, NULL, 'N20015'),
    ('A1', 33.395, 33.44, 0.045, 'DN', 19, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.395, 33.44, 0.045, 'DN', 19, NULL, 'N20033'),
    ('A1', 33.44, 33.485, 0.045, 'BM', 20, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.44, 33.485, 0.045, 'BM', 20, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.44, 33.485, 0.045, 'BM', 20, NULL, 'N20033'),
    ('A1', 33.44, 33.485, 0.045, 'BM', 20, NULL, 'N20034'),
    ('A1', 33.485, 33.51, 0.025, 'DN', 21, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.485, 33.51, 0.025, 'DN', 21, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.485, 33.51, 0.025, 'DN', 21, NULL, 'N20033'),
    ('A1', 33.485, 33.51, 0.025, 'DN', 21, NULL, 'N20034'),
    ('A1', 33.51, 33.595, 0.085, 'DB', 22, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.51, 33.595, 0.085, 'DB', 22, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.51, 33.595, 0.085, 'DB', 22, NULL, 'N20034'),
    ('A1', 33.595, 33.665, 0.07, 'DN', 23, 'N13046', NULL),
    ('A1', 33.595, 33.665, 0.07, 'DN', 23, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.595, 33.665, 0.07, 'DN', 23, NULL, 'N20034'),
    ('A1', 33.665, 33.785, 0.12, 'DB', 24, NULL, 'N2001516'),
    ('A1', 33.785, 33.79, 0.005, 'YS', 25, NULL, NULL),
    ('A1', 33.79, 33.83, 0.04, 'BM', 26, NULL, NULL)
;
```

Appreciate all your help!

Comment: It would be incredibly valuable to maintain consistency of the CSSID and PSSID columns once "pivoted". That is to say if a value occurs in one CSSID column then it will stay "in" that column. See the example of desired output above for reference.

Answer (score 4):

You have already defined the groups creating the `INT` column. We can use it, to make `pivot` for both `PSS` and `CSS` separately and then join them.

```
SELECT *
INTO #DataSourcePSS
FROM
(
    SELECT [INT]
          ,[PSSID]
          ,CONCAT('PSSID',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [INT] ORDER BY [PSSID] DESC)) AS [RowID]
    FROM #SampleData
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([PSSID]) FOR RowID IN ([PSSID1], [PSSID2], [PSSID3], [PSSID4], [PSSID5])
) PVT

SELECT *
INTO #DataSourceCSS
FROM
(
    SELECT [INT]
          ,[CSSID]
          ,CONCAT('CSSID', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [INT] ORDER BY [CSSID] DESC)) AS [RowID] 
    FROM #SampleData
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([CSSID]) FOR RowID IN ([CSSID1], [CSSID2], [CSSID3], [CSSID4], [CSSID5])
) PVT;

WITH DataSourceSD AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [ID], [START], [FINISH], [DURA], [COD], [INT]
    FROM #SampleData
)
SELECT SD.*
      ,PSS.[PSSID1],PSS.[PSSID2],PSS.[PSSID3],PSS.[PSSID4],PSS.[PSSID5]
      ,CSS.[CSSID1],CSS.[CSSID2],CSS.[CSSID3],CSS.[CSSID4],CSS.[CSSID5]
FROM DataSourceSD SD
INNER JOIN #DataSourcePSS PSS
    ON SD.[INT] = PSS.[INT]
INNER JOIN #DataSourceCSS CSS
    ON SD.[INT] = CSS.[INT]
ORDER BY SD.[INT];

DROP TABLE #DataSourceCSS;
DROP TABLE #DataSourcePSS;
DROP TABLE #SampleData;
```

[image]

As you can have up to five values in each group I am pivoting on five values. In this case you can have columns which has not got any values. If this is not `OK` you need to use dynamic PIVOT instead.

Comment: `PIVOT` is great, if there is only one column as target. With more than one  target pivoting is easier with `GROUP BY` and aggregats

Comment: Well, one could discuss the word *easier*... If ever possible I'd prefer *ad-hoc SQL*. You create a temp table, fill it in two steps and create your pivot from there. Your joins and sorting will not be able to use indexes unless you create them explicitly. My ad-hoc SQL was fully inlineable into bigger statements, could be used as `VIEW` or `inline TVF`, while your multi statement approach could only live within a SP - quite a back draw... One could think about CTEs instead of the tmp table... In terms of performance I'm quite sure, that this would be rather slow...

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936804/pivot-vs-case-t-sql-efficiency and here you'll find details about performance: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: Thanks very much! Confirmed as working but really looking to try and keep the SIDs consistent. For example N20033 switches from being CSSID1 to CSSID2 - the preference would be to keep it in CSSID1... Sorry this wasn't clearly stated in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

### UPDATE according to your comment

This is now sorted accoding to the internal numbering of the distinct values of your PSSIDs and CSSIDs. Other than your *desired output* I get 4 values as the N20034 is in a new column. I do not see any logic how to decide in which column a value should pop up... The key for this is the numbering. My first approach numbers the values according to their position relativ to the "parent", this new approach sorts them to get in a distinct column each...

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE WHEN PSSID IS NOT NULL THEN 'PSSID' ELSE 'CSSID' END AS ColumnName  
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Start,Finish,Dura,COD,[INT],CASE WHEN PSSID IS NOT NULL THEN 'PSSID' ELSE 'CSSID' END ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SortNr  
    FROM #SampleData
)
,DistinctPSSIDS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PSSID) AS SortNr
          ,PSSID
    FROM #SampleData
    WHERE PSSID IS NOT NULL
)
,DistinctCSSIDS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CSSID) AS SortNr
          ,CSSID
    FROM #SampleData
    WHERE CSSID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT ID,Start,Finish,Dura,COD,[INT]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='PSSID' AND dp.SortNr=1 THEN n.PSSID END) AS PSSID1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='PSSID' AND dp.SortNr=2 THEN n.PSSID END) AS PSSID2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='PSSID' AND dp.SortNr=3 THEN n.PSSID END) AS PSSID3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='PSSID' AND dp.SortNr=4 THEN n.PSSID END) AS PSSID4
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='PSSID' AND dp.SortNr=5 THEN n.PSSID END) AS PSSID5
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='CSSID' AND dc.SortNr=1 THEN n.CSSID END) AS CSSID1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='CSSID' AND dc.SortNr=2 THEN n.CSSID END) AS CSSID2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='CSSID' AND dc.SortNr=3 THEN n.CSSID END) AS CSSID3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='CSSID' AND dc.SortNr=4 THEN n.CSSID END) AS CSSID4
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN n.ColumnName='CSSID' AND dc.SortNr=5 THEN n.CSSID END) AS CSSID5
FROM Numbered AS n
LEFT JOIN DistinctPSSIDS AS dp ON dp.PSSID=n.PSSID
LEFT JOIN DistinctCSSIDS AS dc ON dc.CSSID=n.CSSID
GROUP BY ID,Start,Finish,Dura,COD,[INT]
```

The result

```
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | Start | Finish | Dura | COD | INT | PSSID1 | PSSID2 | PSSID3 | PSSID4 | PSSID5 | CSSID1 | CSSID2   | CSSID3 | CSSID4 | CSSID5 |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.18 | 33.27  | 0.09 | ST  | 15  | N13045 | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.27 | 33.29  | 0.02 | DU  | 16  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015 | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.29 | 33.35  | 0.07 | BM  | 17  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015 | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.35 | 33.40  | 0.05 | DM  | 18  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015 | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.40 | 33.44  | 0.05 | DN  | 19  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015 | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.44 | 33.49  | 0.05 | BM  | 20  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | N20033 | N20034 | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.49 | 33.51  | 0.03 | DN  | 21  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | N20033 | N20034 | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.51 | 33.60  | 0.09 | DB  | 22  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | NULL   | N20034 | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.60 | 33.67  | 0.07 | DN  | 23  | NULL   | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | NULL   | N20034 | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.67 | 33.79  | 0.12 | DB  | 24  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.79 | 33.79  | 0.01 | YS  | 25  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.79 | 33.83  | 0.04 | BM  | 26  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

### previous: old-fashion-pivot with GROUP BY and aggregats

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE WHEN PSSID IS NOT NULL THEN 'PSSID' ELSE 'CSSID' END AS ColumnName  
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Start,Finish,Dura,COD,[INT],CASE WHEN PSSID IS NOT NULL THEN 'PSSID' ELSE 'CSSID' END ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SortNr  
    FROM #SampleData
)
SELECT ID,Start,Finish,Dura,COD,[INT]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='PSSID' AND SortNr=1 THEN PSSID END) AS PSSID1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='PSSID' AND SortNr=2 THEN PSSID END) AS PSSID2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='PSSID' AND SortNr=3 THEN PSSID END) AS PSSID3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='PSSID' AND SortNr=4 THEN PSSID END) AS PSSID4
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='PSSID' AND SortNr=5 THEN PSSID END) AS PSSID5
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='CSSID' AND SortNr=1 THEN CSSID END) AS CSSID1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='CSSID' AND SortNr=2 THEN CSSID END) AS CSSID2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='CSSID' AND SortNr=3 THEN CSSID END) AS CSSID3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='CSSID' AND SortNr=4 THEN CSSID END) AS CSSID4
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName='CSSID' AND SortNr=5 THEN CSSID END) AS CSSID5
FROM Numbered
GROUP BY ID,Start,Finish,Dura,COD,[INT]
```

The result

```
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | Start | Finish | Dura | COD | INT | PSSID1 | PSSID2 | PSSID3 | PSSID4 | PSSID5 | CSSID1   | CSSID2   | CSSID3 | CSSID4 | CSSID5 |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.18 | 33.27  | 0.09 | ST  | 15  | N13045 | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.27 | 33.29  | 0.02 | DU  | 16  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015   | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.29 | 33.35  | 0.07 | BM  | 17  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015   | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.35 | 33.40  | 0.05 | DM  | 18  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015   | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.40 | 33.44  | 0.05 | DN  | 19  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N20015   | N2001516 | N20033 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.44 | 33.49  | 0.05 | BM  | 20  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | N20033   | N20034 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.49 | 33.51  | 0.03 | DN  | 21  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | N20033   | N20034 | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.51 | 33.60  | 0.09 | DB  | 22  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | N20034   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.60 | 33.67  | 0.07 | DN  | 23  | N13046 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | N20034   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.67 | 33.79  | 0.12 | DB  | 24  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | N2001516 | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.79 | 33.79  | 0.01 | YS  | 25  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| A1 | 33.79 | 33.83  | 0.04 | BM  | 26  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+-------+--------+------+-----+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Prefered over gotqn's answer due to readability. Again same problem though regarding the consistency of SIDs. Can you think of a way it would be possible to keep a CSSID/PSSID in the same column (i.e. in your result output N2001516 goes from being a CSSID2 to CSSID1, it would be better if this was kept in the one column).

Comment: @Harry, How many different values will be there? If you want all identical within the same column you could easily need more than 5 columns...

Comment: Thanks Shnugo! Looking very good. So with your update I'm understanding that the query is limited to 5 PSSIDs in a given ID. If there are more then the query would need to add additional columns otherwise they would go "missing"?

Comment: @Harry, did not see this earlier... Yes, that is a general problem with any kind of pivoting... There are two ways around: Define a sure number of columns and deal with most of them being `NULL` or define the statement as a string dynamically and execute this with `EXEC`. In this case you could even use your value as column names and just set an "X" into the row where it applies. But such a result is only good for presentation... It's very hard to work with this in a later process. The more you know, the better you go...