# Convert rows to columns using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table named AmountList in SQL Server :

[image: AmountList]

where Primary key is " UniqueCol1, UniqueCol2, AmountID "

and on the basis of AmountID I want to Pivot the results as:

[image]

I am facing the challenge using Pivot because only Aggregate functions can be used but I need actual values of the fields.

**UPDATE:** Added my attempt for the solution using JOINS, but need some query with higher performance.

Comment: No success with PIVOT hence used multiple FULL OUTER JOINS to achieve the result. But using joins is a bit slower hence searching for a solution with PIVOT

Comment: Attaching my attempt for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions to achieve your expected output.

```
select
  uniqueCol1,
  uniqueCol2,
  sum(case when AmountID = 1 then amount end) as Amount1MO,
  sum(case when AmountID = 3 then amount end) as Amount3MO,
  sum(case when AmountID = 6 then amount end) as Amount6MO,
  sum(case when AmountID = 9 then amount end) as Amount9MO,
  sum(case when AmountID = 12 then amount end) as Amount12MO
from AmountList
group by
  uniqueCol1,
  uniqueCol2
```

Comment: Thank you @zealous for the solution, it works, but can we use pivot also?

Comment: yeah sure, but can you please guide me, which will have higher performance with respect to data warehouse, the query with CASE or with PIVOT ??

Comment: @TusharRastogi here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936804/pivot-vs-case-t-sql-efficiency

Comment: That's very helpful, Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CASE WHEN t1.uniqueCol1 is not null THEN t1.uniqueCol1
WHEN t2.uniqueCol1 is not null THEN t2.uniqueCol1
t3.uniqueCol1 is not null THEN t3.uniqueCol1
t4.uniqueCol1 is not null THEN t4.uniqueCol1
t5.uniqueCol1 is not null THEN t5.uniqueCol1
ELSE NULL END AS uniqueCol1,
CASE WHEN t1.uniqueCol2 is not null THEN t1.uniqueCol2
WHEN t2.uniqueCol2 is not null THEN t2.uniqueCol2
t3.uniqueCol2 is not null THEN t3.uniqueCol2
t4.uniqueCol2 is not null THEN t4.uniqueCol2
t5.uniqueCol2 is not null THEN t5.uniqueCol2
ELSE NULL END AS uniqueCol2,
Amount1MO,Amount3MO,Amount6MO,Amount9MO,Amount12MO from

    (
    select
      uniqueCol1,
      uniqueCol2,
      Amount as Amount1MO,
    from AmountList
    where AmountID = 1
    )t1

        FULL OUTER JOIN

    (
    select
      uniqueCol1,
      uniqueCol2,
      Amount as Amount3MO,
    from AmountList
    where AmountID = 3
    )t2

        ON t1.uniqueCol1=t2.uniqueCol1 AND t1.uniqueCol2 = t2.uniqueCol2
        FULL OUTER JOIN

    (
    select 
      uniqueCol1,
      uniqueCol2,
      Amount as Amount6MO,
    from AmountList
    where AmountID = 6
    )t3

        ON t2.uniqueCol1=t3.uniqueCol1 AND t2.uniqueCol2 = t3.uniqueCol2
        FULL OUTER JOIN

    (
    select
      uniqueCol1,
      uniqueCol2,
      Amount as Amount9MO,
    from AmountList
    where AmountID = 9
    )t4

        ON t3.uniqueCol1=t4.uniqueCol1 AND t3.uniqueCol2 = t4.uniqueCol2
        FULL OUTER JOIN

    (
    select
      uniqueCol1,
      uniqueCol2,
      Amount as Amount12MO,
    from AmountList
    where AmountID = 12
    )t5
```